# Log suspend reason unknown

Tags: sybase

I am not a DBA but a programmer. Recently we have been getting LOG SUSPEND issue daily on our production. I am unable to catch the scenario as it is not reproducible on my local system.
A file when uploaded on production fails with log suspend while same file uploaded on local seems to work fine. Also, when the same file is uploaded again after some time it seems to work fine in production too. 
Really confused as why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Log Suspend indicates that the transaction log is filling up, and may not be properly sized for the transaction rate you are supporting.  Have the DBA/System Administrator add additional Log device space to the database that is having issues.  If possible, you may also want to break up any large transactions as well to lower the possibility

As for a cause, it's very dependent on how the system is setup.  First check the database settings.

`sp_helpdb` will print out the list of databases on the server, as well as any options that may be set for each database.

If you don't see `trunc log on chkpt`, then the database is setup for maximum recoverability, the log space will only free up after a backup is run, or after the transaction log is dumped.  This allows for up to the second recovery in the event of a failure, at the expense of using more log space.

If you DO see `trunc log on chkpt`, then the database will automatically truncate the log after a checkpoint occurs in the database.  Checkpoints are issued by the database itself as part of routine processing, but the command can also be issued manually.  If this option is set, and the database still goes into log suspend, then you may have a transaction that did not properly close (whether by committing or rolling back).  You can check the `master..syslogshold` table to find long running transactions.

A third possibility is that if the system is using SAP/Sybase Replication Server, there is actually a secondary truncation point used as part of the replication processes.  The system will not truncate the transaction log until after a transaction has been read by the RepAgent process, so this too can cause a system to go into log suspend.

Comment: Thanks Michael
To me it appears to be 3rd option. Any idea how can we tackle this?

Comment: @shrutirawat Adding additional log space will help.  In addition, you'll want to see if you can break up some of your transactions into smaller pieces, as large transactions can cause delays in replication.  Also check to make sure that there aren't any undiagnosed issues with the Replication link (network degradation, indexes on destination server, etc).